# Location for SSL debug logging in java

Tags: ssl, logging

I am trying to debug a java application using property - System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl"); in my main class.

I see debug logs in console when I run application using Eclipse during development. However, when I try to run same application using webstart I am not able to see any debug logs in any directory so far. 
Is there a specific location where this logs are stored during execution?

I also tried passing debug option to run the jar from command line as java -Djavax.net.debug=ssl -jar xyz.jar but still cannot find logs generated.
Can anyone please help me understand to obtain SSL debug logs for java application?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't stored anywhere. They are printed to `System.out` or `System.err`.

Comment: u can dump this to a file using                                           PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("syslog_.log"));
   System.setOut(printStream);
   System.setErr(printStream);

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, from command line you can write debug output directly into a file:

```
java -Djavax.net.debug=all -jar xyz.jar > out.log
```

Comment: This isn't working on Mac OS.